# What changes needed for use {TENANT_ID}.mydomain.com instead of {TENANCY_NAME}.mydomain.com?- Asp.NET Zero

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Asp.NET Zero With Angular 8. Currently I'm using `{TENANCY_NAME}.mydomain.com` for direct tenant login.
I want to use `{TENANT_ID}.mydomain.com` instead of `{TENANCY_NAME}.mydomain.com` for direct tenant login.
What kind of changes I should do and at where?